# C: Erro no srand(time(NULL));

Tags: c

Estou fazendo um joguinho em C(projeto faculdade) e estou encontrando um erro no main, segue:

```
int main () {
    int x, y, i, j, linha, cnt=1, jl=0, jc=0, jogada_a=0, jogada_b=0;
    char coluna, jogador;
    srand(time(NULL));
    x = (rand() % 5) +2;
    y = (rand() % 5) +2;
    gerar();
    matriz[x][y] = '0';
}
```

O erro pede declaração de time:

> error: 'time' was not declared in this scope

Answer (score 7):

Faltou a inclusão dos *headers*:

```
#include <stdlib.h>  /* rand(), srand() */
#include <time.h>    /* time() */
```

Comment: @gfleck você sugeriu uma edição nessa pergunta que desvia a opinião do próprio autor da resposta. Se não se importar, poste como outra resposta, se vier a ajudar o autor da pergunta (AP).

Answer (score -1):

Depois da função `srand(time(NULL))` é necessário que use FOR.

Comment: Quando possível, exemplifique como o código ficará